# Is it possible to change the default user of docker minio/minio:latest from root to any other username/group?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am using minio/minio:latest image in my docker-compose.yaml file, and I want the minio docker container to have a user other than root.

after checking the /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh shipped with the image (see below), I found that the username and group can be set using the environment variables: `MINIO_USERNAME` and `MINIO_GROUPNAME`.

However I am getting the following error:

```
minio  | Time: 14:09:00 UTC 03/19/2024
minio  | Error: unable to create (/data/.minio.sys/tmp) file access denied, drive may be faulty please investigate (*fmt.wrapError)
minio  |        6: internal/logger/logger.go:260:logger.LogIf()
minio  |        5: cmd/prepare-storage.go:96:cmd.bgFormatErasureCleanupTmp()
minio  |        4: cmd/xl-storage.go:291:cmd.newXLStorage()
minio  |        3: cmd/object-api-common.go:63:cmd.newStorageAPI()
minio  |        2: cmd/format-erasure.go:706:cmd.initStorageDisksWithErrors.func1()
minio  |        1: github.com/minio/pkg/v2@v2.0.11/sync/errgroup/errgroup.go:123:errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
minio  | ERROR Unable to use the drive /data: file access denied: Invalid arguments specified
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
---
services:
    minio:
        image: minio/minio:latest
        container_name: minio
        volumes:
            - minio:/data
        environment:
            MINIO_USERNAME: ouss
            MINIO_GROUPNAME: ouss
        command: server /data
        restart: always
volumes:
  - minio
```

and the `docker-entrypoint.sh`, shipped with the minio image

```
#!/bin/sh
#

# If command starts with an option, prepend minio.
if [ "${1}" != "minio" ]; then
    if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
        set -- minio "$@"
    fi
fi

docker_switch_user() {
    if [ -n "${MINIO_USERNAME}" ] && [ -n "${MINIO_GROUPNAME}" ]; then
        if [ -n "${MINIO_UID}" ] && [ -n "${MINIO_GID}" ]; then
            chroot --userspec=${MINIO_UID}:${MINIO_GID} / "$@"
        else
            echo "${MINIO_USERNAME}:x:1000:1000:${MINIO_USERNAME}:/:/sbin/nologin" >>/etc/passwd
            echo "${MINIO_GROUPNAME}:x:1000" >>/etc/group
            chroot --userspec=${MINIO_USERNAME}:${MINIO_GROUPNAME} / "$@"
        fi
    else
        exec "$@"
    fi
}

## DEPRECATED and unsupported - switch to user if applicable.
docker_switch_user "$@"
```